# how to remove margin introduced in pre tag in bootstrap 4?

Tags: bootstrap-4

i am using pre tag to display some text using bootstrap 4. So the problem is that it is introducing spaces which shows the text slider. I want to remove that please i need your help. I am still new to bootstrap.

[![shown in this image][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/peu1W.jpg

````
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <pre>
                            &lt;p&gt;I love programming!&lt;/p&gt;
                            &lt;p&gt;This paragraph is on my landing page&lt;/p&gt;
                            &lt;br/&gt;
                            &lt;br/&gt;
                            &lt;p&gt;Bootstrap by example&lt;/p&gt;
                        </pre>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <img src="imgs/center.png" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                </div>  ```
````

Comment: is there any css defined with this pre tag?

Comment: Are you sure your problem is not simply due to the space before each tag?

Comment: @AnkushRasgon no just the pure bootstrap classes

Comment: @NoDataFound it is ! but why ? i program with tabs to have clean to read but why the pre tag would use the space and not ignore it ?

Comment: That's simply the purpose of <pre> tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) : print the content of the tag as typed; space are part of the tag, hence your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i run your code and found that problem is just because of too much space on left hand side

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <pre>
       &lt;p&gt;I love programming!&lt;/p&gt;
       &lt;p&gt;This paragraph is on my landing page&lt;/p&gt;
       &lt;br/&gt;
       &lt;br/&gt;
       &lt;p&gt;Bootstrap by example&lt;/p&gt;
     </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes true just did it ! but as i said in the previous comment i did not know that pre would use the existing spaces !